# Display Default page until server starts

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc, jetty

I want to display a default custom page until my server starts completely.

Problem Statement : I am doing few setup things when the server starts, so it takes a very long time for the server to start. So in the meantime server stats if some user hits the home page url, so he should see some default page showing server is starting..blah blah...

Now the issue is if server is not started completely, neither my application context is loaded fully, and the response for the hit is "aborted", which is not a HTTP response, so how can i catch this response and show some error page.

Server can be jetty, tomcat any

Comment: If the server hasn't been fully initialized it cannot serve requests.

Comment: yes correct..but is there a way i can do something to show some default page until server is started...

Comment: There sure is.  Artifactory does it for example.  However, you are going to have to move your long setup code out of the servlet initialization and into some other background worker thread.  The servlet initialization should just kick off your worker thread.  You then should have a servlet which checks to see if your application is initialized and responds appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty example:

```
public class DeferringServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DeferringServlet.class);

  private MyApp myApp;
  private Thread appInitializerThread;

  public void init() {
    myApp = new MyApp();
    appInitializerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        myApp.init();
      }
    });
    appInitializerThread.start();
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    if(myApp.isInitialized()) {
      myApp.doGet(req, resp);
    } else {
      myApp.setStatus(503); //Service unavailable
      myApp.getWriter.println("Please wait.  App is loading");
    }
  }

  public void destroy() {
    if(appInitializerThread.isAlive()) {
      appInitializerThread.interrupt();
    }
    try {
      appInitializerThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      logger.warn("Interrupted before app initializer could finish");
    }
  }

}
```